# Running python codes from outside the directory when script has filepaths

Tags: python, python-3.4, cd

So I have a python script `my_script.py` which is inside the folder `Test` and I am outside this folder. The script requires to access some input data from the file `my_data.dat` stored inside the folder `Test`.

Now, when I try to run this script from outside the folder `Test`, using simple `python my_script.py`, it tries to locate `my_data.dat` in the folder from which I am running the script and so fails. How can I tell it use the correct path without actually modifying the path in the my_script.py?

I don't want to modify the paths in the script because the script is to be used generically for various paths and the whole thing would be automated later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use absolute file path instead of the relative file path.

To get absolute path of directory containing python file:

```
import os
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

And you can get absolute path of `my_data.dat`

```
data_file_path = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'my_data.dat')
```

Afterward use `data_file_path` instead of `"my_data.dat"`

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass the path to `my_data.dat` as a parameter to the script, or (if the data file is always in the same directory as the  script) you can use the variable `__file__` to determine where the script is and look for the data file in that directory.